# Daterangepicker picker ranges not displaying

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-daterangepicker

[I integrated daterangepicker to my application. It was working properly suddenly ranges was not appearing by default custom is selected and all other options are not displaying.I have attached screenshot with this. Can anyone help me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kiaiv.png
.

Comment: can you provide code in fiddle or snippet. then i can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got the issues. It was because i have used maxDate: '@DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")'  in option set. I removed the format so that issue solved.

Answer (score 1):

check the max date and set it future date or past date .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")' in option set